# Lightbox not working or adding rel=lightbox to image links in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Please forgive my ignorance.  I'm running WordPress 3.5 and just installed Lightbox Plus.  I've checked and double checked setting and it should be automatically adding the `rel="lightbox[uniqueID|filename]"` attribute to image links, but it's not.

I've checked my header.php and the hook `"<?php wp_head(); ?>"` is there.

Here's the link added form the gallery.

```
<a href="http://dreamlandhomes.ca/wp-content/uploads/5703-Elizabeth-A-main.png"><img class="aligncenter size-thumbnail wp-image-1556" alt="5703-Elizabeth-A-main" src="http://dreamlandhomes.ca/wp-content/uploads/5703-Elizabeth-A-main-150x150.png" width="150" height="150" /></a>
```

I've tried manually installing the attribute, but it doesn't work either.  just opens the image in a new tab.

Example 2 (manually imputed rel)

```
<a href="http://webaddresshere/wp-content/uploads/5703-Elizabeth-A-main.png" rel="lightbox[test box]"><img class="aligncenter size-thumbnail wp-image-1556" alt="5703-Elizabeth-A-main" src="http://webaddresshere/wp-content/uploads/5703-Elizabeth-A-main-150x150.png" width="150" height="150" /></a>
```

Comment: I'd something similar one time, I think that is a plugin-conflict, try to disable the others and then check again

Comment: can you add a link to the "live" problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a script conflict issue, I seem to have this same problem all the time.

If you're not 100% set on using Lightbox Plus then give Fancybox a shot, it's always worked for me when Lightbox Plus hasn't.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/

Can also be added manually (the Fancybox script) and then triggered automatically for all links that link to an image file using this code:

```
 var select = $('a[href$=".bmp"],a[href$=".gif"],a[href$=".jpg"],a[href$=".jpeg"],a[href$=".png"],a[href$=".BMP"],a[href$=".GIF"],a[href$=".JPG"],a[href$=".JPEG"],a[href$=".PNG"],.fancybox');

 $(select).fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
            }
        }
    }
 });
```

**Update** You don't need the helpers, that's where you put config options if you have any - see the Fancybox docs.